# How to include a //@sourceUrl into an ASP.Net MVC Razor page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to include the following into my page

```
//@@ sourceUrl=MoveReservation.js 
(which should be become //@ sourceUrl=MoveReservation.js)
```

The problem is that this gets wrapped in quotes by the Razor engine.  I tried using @: but tht didn't work and neither does `<text></text>`.

So how would I put something like this into the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless told otherwise, the Razor View Engine will HTML encode any text that it outputs.

You can use @[Html.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) to output a string without it being HTML Encoded

> Returns markup that is not HTML encoded.

```
@Html.Raw("//@ sourceUrl=MoveReservation.js");
```

Comment: Please note, that //@ sourceUrl syntax is obsolete. Please use **//# sourceURL=somefile.js** instead